# Module react-native-web/jest/serializer in the snapshotSerializers option was not found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-native-web

Trying to commit React code to GitHub, when i pushed the code, got this problem

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'injection' of undefined
```

[image]

To solve this problem, updated react-native-web package to `0.17.0`. Then this problem solved but ended up with below error

```
Module react-native-web/jest/serializer in the snapshotSerializers option was not found
```

[image]

Tried to solve this problem but didn't get much discussions in online except [this](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/1012#issuecomment-414444951) (i didn't get what is he telling exactly)

Any one know, how to solve this problem